# loadView and Black Screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I added `loadView` to my LoginController and now my app get black screen after launch images.
Whats the best way to fix that?
Theres any way to run `autoLogin` in launch images?

AppDelegate.h

```
// Load Login View
UIViewController *loadView = [[[LoginViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = loadView;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

LoginController.h:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [self autoLogin];
    [super loadView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loadView is only used to build up your view programmatically when view is referenced the first time. What you probably want instead is viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own UIView and set it to self.view

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [UIView alloc] initWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```